# Select element, which contains element with class x?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a bunch of articles and want to select the first `article`-Element that contains a `button` which has the class `add-to-cart-button` and doesn't have the class `btn--disabled`.

What is the best way to do this with webdriver?

Comment: Do you need to select first article on page only if condition is met or first article that meet condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to select *article* that contains *button with class "add-to-cart-button" and no class "btn--disabled"*:

```
//article[.//button[contains(@class, "add-to-cart-button") and not(contains(@class, "btn--disabled"))]]
```

Comment: but this will select all the elements with given condition we have to use indexing also to get first element meeting the condition as given in question 
"I have a bunch of articles and want to select the first article-"

Comment: If OP wants the first node, no indexing required as in Selenium FindElement method will return the first one (required one)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, xpath provide not() function and then used indexing over xpath to get first element

```
 (//button[not(@class,'btn--disabled') and contains(@class,'add-to-cart-button')])[1]
```